# Operating System not found on VMWare Pro 2015

Tags: vmware-workstation

I attempt to install WinXP file on vmware using iso file with all settings below:

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eh03B.png)

However, when running, the console tells me that Operating System not found
[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TBEf.png).

I also check "connect at power on", reboot the VMware but no effect. Can you tell me what the problem is and how to solve it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is your media? ISO or something else? is it bootable?

Comment: this is winxp iso. I downloaded it on [link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/Download/confirmation.aspx?id=18242).

Answer (score 0):

File provided by link in comment is ServicePack 2 for Windows XP - it's not media with operating system. VMware shows truth on console, because it's not operating system, but package with updates for Windows XP. Conclusion: you have to download bootable operating system media.

In addition even if you will find any bootable media you have to remember, that you **must** pay for license key. Windows XP is no longer supported by Microsoft, but it is not freeware product.